# RTD - convert measured voltage to temperature

Tags: voltage, adc, instrumentation-amplifier, wheatstone-bridge, rtd

I have a 3-wire RTD connected to a Wheatstone bridge and then to a INA. The Vout from the INA is then connected to a ADC. How can I convert the measured voltage from the ADC to the respective temperature and/or the resistance from the RTD?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an equation. Depending on the excitation scheme you'll have a voltage that is related by a simple equation to the resistance.

Once you have the sensor resistance in Ω, you can apply the Callendar–Van Dusen equation to find the temperature. The reverse function is required, so you can do that with a simple binary search (one bit per evaluation). There are approximate [inverse equation](https://rdccontrol.com/thermocouples/rtds-101/temperature-calculations/)s too.

Or use your favorite curve-fit method (eg. polynomial, cubic spline, linear interpolation etc.) to data calculated by the combination of  the two above equations.

If the excitation is by a series resistor rather than constant current the resistance will not be a linear function of measured voltage.